# Syntax error on token "<", invalid AssignmentOperator

Tags: java

```
public void run() {       This line is fine
    OpenCrate.this.results.put(p, Integer.valueOf(((Integer)OpenCrate.this.results.get(p)).intValue() + 1)); This line is fine
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {   This line is fine
      ItemStack it = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, (short)(new Random().nextInt(15) + 1));         This line is fine
      m = it.getItemMeta();          This line is fine
      m.setDisplayName(" ");         This line is fine
      it.setItemMeta(m);             This line is fine
      inv.setItem(i, it);            This line is fine
    }
    List longlist = new ArrayList(); This line is fine
    String s;                        This line is fine
    int i;                           This line is fine
    for (ItemMeta m = CrateResult.getResults().iterator(); m.hasNext(); This line is fine
      i < new CrateResult(s).getChance())  *The Error shows in this line*
    {
      s = (String)m.next();       This line is fine
      i = 0; continue;            This line is fine
      longlist.add(s);            This line is fine

      i++;                        This line is fine
    }
```

I get that error on this symbol "<" as invalid Assignment, This is MC Plugin.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop syntax is wrong. It should be `for (initialization; condition; assignment)`, but you're doing `for (initialization; condition; condition)`;

If you have multiple conditions, you can use the and `&&` operator to combine them.

Comment: Hi Codebender, Thank you for reply, the first code you just post fixed it and then it gave me 2 more Errors in the same line

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `;` at the end of the `for` loop, as well as the `&&` operator.
You have to make it:

```
for (ItemMeta m = CrateResult.getResults().iterator(); m.hasNext() &&
i < new CrateResult(s).getChance());) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beause the third part of a `for` loop is used for storing a value (not testing a condition). I suspect you wanted `&&` like

```
for (ItemMeta m = CrateResult.getResults().iterator(); m.hasNext() &&
        i < new CrateResult(s).getChance();) {
```